# Endless Looping due to NOT IN query Access 2013 SQL

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I am trying to pull out all phone numbers that are in 1 table (A) that are *not* in another table (B).  I've tried LEFT OUTER JOIN's but that never stays very long.  As soon as I go to datasheet and back to SQL it goes back to LEFT JOIN.

That said, here's my code.

```
SELECT tblA.[Phone Number]
FROM tblA LEFT JOIN tblB ON tblA.[Phone Number] = tblB.[Wireless Number]
WHERE (((tblA.[Phone Number]) NOT IN (SELECT [Wireless Number] FROM 
[tblB])));
```

Trouble that I'm having over regular "not in's" that i've done is that the Wireless Number has "-"'s in it and the Phone Number does not.  The Wireless data is external data that I don't want to have to modify for ease of use.  Simply put, I don't want to modify anything in tblB.

If someone has a simpler way of finding values not in another table, I'm all ears.  This NOT IN feature is killing me.  Thanks in advance.

When I run the code above.  Access just spools up and nothing ever happens.  It seems to crash Access. Not sure what it's doing.

Comment: Access has a query wizard for exactly your problem - I suggest you use it and then analyze the SQL it creates. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_access/ms_access_unmatched_query_wizard.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is the - dashes, just remove them using `Replace`:

```
SELECT tblA.[Phone Number]
FROM tblA
WHERE tblA.[Phone Number] NOT IN (SELECT Replace([Wireless Number], "-", "") FROM [tblB]);
```

Also, there's no need for a left join. A `Not In` is a subquery, so you don't need to worry about that.

If a phone number could be `Null`, or performance is important, a `Not Exists` is often preferred over `Not In`:

```
SELECT tblA.[Phone Number]
FROM tblA
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [tblB] WHERE Replace(tblB.[Wireless Number], "-", "") =  tblA.[Phone Number]);
```

Comment: Just a clarification on "...(SELECT 1..."  What is the "1" referring to?

Comment: It's the number one. Nothing else. The subquery needs to return something to check if a record exists. Using 1 instead of a column is faster, and it's convention. But you might as well use 5. Or a string. It doesn't matter.

Comment: Also the NOT EXISTS is great as it is quite a bit faster.

Comment: As a follow up Access 2013 changed it from "NOT EXISTS" to "...WHERE Exists({sql chain}) = False.  For anyone who wants to know.